# React handling outside clicks to close custom button menu component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have a button menu component I've created that acts as a simple "action" menu to use in table on a per row basis. I'm having an issue handling outside clicks to close the menu when it is visible. I currently have a listener that gets attached when the button is clicked and it works fine when only a single button-menu component is being rendered. However when I have multiple being rendered (like in a table), they all react to the same events - ie. the user clicks outside and they all open/close together at the same time. How can I make it so that they all respond individually?

Sample code of what I have below:

```
export default class MenuButton extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.node = React.createRef();

        this.state = {
            showMenu: false,
        }
    }

    handleOutsideClick = (e) => {
        // Ignore clicks on the component itself
        if (this.node.current.contains(e.target)) {
            return;
        }

        this.handleButtonClick();
    }

    handleButtonClick = () => {
        if (!this.state.show) {
            // Attach/remove event handler depending on state of component
            document.addEventListener('click', this.handleOutsideClick, false);
        } else {
            document.removeEventListener('click', this.handleOutsideClick, false);
        }

        this.setState({
            showMenu: !this.state.showMenu,
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Button
                    text="Actions"
                    onClick={this.handleButtonClick}
                    ref={this.node}
                    menuTrigger
                />
                <Menu anchor={this.node.current} visible={this.state.showMenu}>
                    <Menu.Group title={this.props.groupTitle}>
                        {this.props.children}
                    </Menu.Group>
                </Menu>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

So my problem was due to a typo in my code that I noticed. I have a `showMenu` state, but in my `handleButtonClick` I was checking `this.state.show` instead of `this.state.showMenu`.